# Is there a way to start playing an mp3 file in the "middle" without forcing the entire thing to download?

Tags: javascript, audio, mp3, web-audio-api

Let's say I have a 30 minute long mp3 file and, when clicking a button, I want to start playing/streaming a 20 second chunk from at the 10:04 through 10:24, without forcing the user to download the entire file.

Is this possible? Would I need something fancy like a "streaming server" setup or can I accomplish this with the Web Audio API?

Comment: We use [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) here to play audio, and there [is a way to do what you are asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045338/start-audio-download-half-way-through-file), although I have not tried it.

Comment: HTML Audio/Video has a currentTime property that can be set, though I haven't tried that either ;)

Comment: [MSE](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) may be of help. Some useful implementation info [here](http://blog.wirewax.com/building-a-media-source-html5-player/).